# Как определить параметры тренда?

Tags: математика

Есть уравнение, которое наверное должно описывать тренд по ряду данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал найти параметры методом наименьших квадратов, но встретился с проблемой. При составлении системы уравнений происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой момент как
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
не понимаю как разложить, потому что Yx это фактические значения.

Возможно МНК не подходит здесь или я допустил ошибку, когда расписывал систему уравнений. Прошу помощи!

Comment: "которое наверное должно описывать тренд" - но это не точно?

Comment: @Igor - суть в том, что мне нужно найти параметры уравнения. Наверное с помощью него можно построить тренд для какого-нибудь временного ряда. Я просто пытался вывести формулы для определения параметров через МНК, но не вышло, здесь я привёл упрощённый пример, чтобы указать на проблему без излишеств =)

Comment: МНК для такой формулы дадут нелинейные уравнения. Потому всегда для всяких зависимостей типа логарифмических или степенных их сначала линеаризуют (и совершенно не учитывают то, что при этом погрешности кардинально изменяются, но это уже второй вопрос). Линеаризовать вашу зависимость не получится, так что - или решать систему нелинейных уравнений, или пробовать как-то иначе (впрочем, иначе все равно упрется в нелинейные уравнения...) У вас так четко прописаны синус и косинус, что, может, попробовать Фурье-анализ?

Comment: @Harry, почитаю о решении систем нелинейных уравнений, если не получится, попробую Фурье-анализ, спасибо!